# IonViewDidEnter “Promise” ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I am trying to load 3 methods inside the ionViewDidEnter but always the first method after this.carregacarrinho() does not run. Why ?

```
ionViewDidEnter() {


this.carregaCarrinho()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("ok");
  }, (error) => {
    this.database.presentToast("Não foi possível carregar o carrinho");
  })

  this.database.buscaTipoeCliente()
      .then((data) => {
        this.tipovenda = data[0].tipovenda;
        this.cliente = data[0].cliente;
        this.codigo = data[0].codigo;
        this.database.presentToast(this.tipovenda);
        this.database.presentToast(this.cliente);
        this.database.presentToast(this.codigo);
      }, (error) => {
        this.database.presentToast("Não possível carregar Condição de venda, cliente e código");
      })


  this.database.buscaUsuario()
  .then((user) => { 
    this.usuario = user;
    this.database.presentToast(this.usuario);
  });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way to use promises, use then nested so, if a error occurs, you can see where did it happens. And if someday you need to load something to use it in another method in the same function it can have some concurrency problems. Do like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.carregaCarrinho()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("ok");

                this.database.buscaTipoeCliente()
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.tipovenda = data[0].tipovenda;
                        this.cliente = data[0].cliente;
                        this.codigo = data[0].codigo;
                        this.database.presentToast(this.tipovenda);
                        this.database.presentToast(this.cliente);
                        this.database.presentToast(this.codigo);

                        this.database.buscaUsuario()
                            .then((user) => {
                                this.usuario = user;
                                this.database.presentToast(this.usuario);
                            });
                    }, (error) => {
                        this.database.presentToast("Não possível carregar Condição de venda, cliente e código");
                    })
            }, (error) => {
                this.database.presentToast("Não foi possível carregar o carrinho");
            })
    }
```

If you need to call the functions even if `this.carregaCarrinho()` fails, then call then on the error callback. I know the code i'll be larger, but it'll be the best way for you to see if there's something wrong in your code.

Just a tip: Don't know if there's a loading somewhere, but `ionViewDidEnter` only executes when the view enter (as the name says), it's not good to let the user waiting to much to se something in the screen. So put a loading or use `ionViewWillEnter()`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just a tip: You could handle all your calls an Promise.all() which runs all promises together. https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: WOW DIDNT KNOW THAT THANKS YOU, for that case it's so much simpler.